# How to convert this specific date and time to a different format?

Tags: php

I got this timestamp from the facebook feed. What I need is to convert iHow can I convert the following date & time and add another 1 hour to the result?

```
2014-05-28T06:47:05+01:00
```

to `28/05 08:47` ?

Thank you

Comment: Might not be an exact duplicate but the answers there pretty much cover the same situation

Comment: How do you indicate the timezone for 08:47?

Answer (score 2):

```
// Convert to a DateTime object
$dateTime = new DateTime('2014-05-28T06:47:05+01:00');
$dateTime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));

// Add an hour (as you requested)
$dateTime->add(new DateInterval('PT1H'));

// Display formatted date/time
echo $dateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

or your timezone of choice

Comment: It looks like the datetime string already has a timezone offset, so convertng it to UTC may have unintended results.

Comment: @OscarM. - which is precisely why I asked for any clarification; though the +01:00 could also be DST

Answer (score 0):

You use `strtotime` to convert the time to an integer, then use `date` to convert it back to a string in the format you'd like.